# Adjust Width & Height of a Control (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, controls, height, width

I am just starting to study ASP.NET from my WPF Knowledge. I think the UI designing is very difficult in ASP.NET compared to WPF XAML design.

I have a problem in my UI layout. In WPF we use **Width=" * " and Height=" * "**  to adjust height and width of the controls like listview, listbox so that the application can run in any resolution without overlapping ? What is the alternate way to set height and width in ASP.NET?

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you'll want to be setting the style's of your controlls using CSS.

If you have a control that has a CssClass="myControl" then in your CSS you'll be able to do the following:

```
.myControl{
    width: *px;
    height:*px;
}
```

Where * is a numerical value. You can also change the value type from px to % and other value types.

Using a % value type will allow you to cater for multiple resolutions whilst retaining a similar feel to your application.

Answer (score 0):

Use '%' for specifying height and width.

> Specified as a  of
>   containing block's width.

Read

[width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/width) and [height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/height)